# Access violation writing location while filling the matrix

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix

```
char *inputForMidTask(int &n, char **ptr) {
    printf("Enter the amount of rows: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            gets_s(*(ptr + i), 100); //throws exception here
    }
    return *ptr;
}

void byString() {
    int n;
    char **ptr = (char**)malloc(255 * 255 * sizeof(char));
    *ptr = inputForMidTask(n, m, ptr);
}
```

Hello! I need to fill in the matrix string by string, but I keep getting an exception error - Exception thrown at 0x78D6FA8D (ucrtbased.dll) in Lab2_Algs.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.
P.S. Memory for **ptr is allocated dynamically by using function malloc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Complete code is needed. Please see this: [mre]. Also, please take  the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: My guess is that the caller didn't allocate memory for the array of strings, you're supposed to do the memory allocation in the function.

Comment: I tried to do the memory allocation in that function, but it didnt go well, I got an exception that said like: "nullptr".

Comment: `int &n` is C++. C doesn't have reference variables.

Comment: Your memory allocation does not allocate what you think it allocates.  You will need to allocate a block of 255 pointers, and then for each of those pointers, allocate a block of 255 characters.  Or something approximately equivalent to that.   And `int &n` in the argument list is C++, not C.

Comment: actually I am coding in cpp, but I have to use C language for my CS lessons. About &n:
pointer didnt work well, so temporiary I use references

Comment: So, don't use C++-only features in C programs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char **ptr` means it's an array of pointers. But you allocated an array of `255*255` characters, not pointers.

It should be:

```
char **ptr = malloc(255 * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    ptr[i] = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
}
```

You also never set `n` before calling `inputForMidTask()`.

And there's not much point in returning `*ptr`. That's just returning the first line.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Your `byString` function allocates one huge buffer but your `inputForMidTask` function expects `n` small buffers. It's not clear how to fix it because there is no explanation of what `inputForMidTask` is supposed to do. Most likely, it should be changed to allocate `n` small buffers and `byString` should be changed only to allocate enough space to hold the pointers to the small buffers.